# How to restrict orientation of alertview on orientation change of device in ios8

Tags: ios8, uialertview

In iOS 8 in my app when I changed the orientation of device at that time UIAlertview also get changed to  respective Orientation.I want to restrict it.I want alertview fixed to be in Portrait mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS8,system provide a new class UIAlertController replay UIAlertView and UIActionSheet，This is a FYAlertView that support iOS8 and iOS8 before use UIALertView and UIActionSheet https://github.com/wangyangcc/FYAlertManage

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code it may help you .

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(alertView.transform, degreesToRadian(90));
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: `didPresentAlertView` is not being called for me.. any clue ?